# Count the number of score Combinations

Tags: algorithm

This is a question from book Elements of Programming Interviews.
You have an aggregate score s and W which specifies the points that
can be scored in an individual play. How would you find the number of combinations of plays that result in an aggregate score of s? How would you compute the number of distinct sequences of individual plays that result in a score of s?

Eg:-

> W = { 2,3,7 } and s = 12, then the ***result is 4*** - { 2x6,2x3+3x2,
>   2x1+3x1+7x1, 3x4 }

And the solution as given in book is -

```
 int count_permutations (int k, const vector <int >& score_ways ) {
     vector <int> permutations (k + 1, 0);
     permutations [0] = 1; // one way to reach 0.
     for (int i = 0; i <= k; ++i) {
        for (const int& score : score_ways ) {
           if (i >= score) {
              permutations [i] += permutations [i - score ];
           } 
         }
     }
     return permutations [k];
}
```

My question is - doesn't this algorithm giving all the permutation of sequence instead of combination as asked ?

Comment: link of the book [link](https://b75e076bd82fe9406dd2c54a902556bba6240685.googledrive.com/host/0BxSo5a62h0DfSzUtZDd2bklGTTA/EPI-Sample/epi-light-1.4.4.pdf) qn-17.2

Comment: it gives exactly what's needed, what exactly you think is wrong?

Comment: It gives the solution 18 for the above example instead of 4

Comment: `distinct sequences of individual plays` : each player treated differently, so permutation is correct .

Comment: @AyushShukla in this case answer is not 4

Comment: Make sense. In that case, the example written in the book was wrong then.

Comment: @AyushShukla the example you've written is not for this question in the book, it's for previous problem

Answer (score 0):

The *permutation* is *ordered* thus will generate more result than the *combination*. Permutation for this triplet {1, 2, 3} is (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1) following the general form n!=(n−1)×(n−2)×⋯×3×2×1. The code shown there is for a *permutation* even if you don't see a factorial expression hidden by the enclosed loop ***for***.

Comment: In permutation order does matter. So, for the above example W={2,3,7} and s=5, the algorithm gives 5 as {2,3} and {3,2}. That means, the code shown is for permutation

Comment: Its in 155-156 in the link

Comment: Hi Ayush, I checked the exercise, it's for permutation.

Comment: Yes Elnineo, the problem statement seemed a bit confusing to me!

Comment: In a mathematical combinatorial sense this isn't nor arrangement nor a permutation.